Why can`t DSolve solve this second order ode with initial conditions?
This ode from textbook.  I was surprised Mathematica 14.1 on windows could not solve it, as one can solve it using Mathematica by solving for initial conditions directly.
So I am hoping some debugging expert could give a hint why it could not solve it. It will be both interesting and educational to learn why.
DSolve can solve it with no initial conditions. But once the IC are added is where it becomes not happy.
ClearAll[y, x]
ode = D[y[x], {x, 2}] == D[y[x], x]*Exp[y[x]]
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 2}
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]

Gives
DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions.    
DSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by DSolve, so some solutions may not be found.
{}

Let us now solve it step by step using Mathematica. We see we can easily find the solution
sol = DSolveValue[ode, y[x], x]


Now we setup two equations from the two initial conditions and solve the two constants, just like we do when solving this by hand:
eq1 = 0 == sol /. x -> 0;
eq2 = 2 == (D[sol, x]) /. x -> 0;
solC = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {C[1], C[2]}]


Substituting these constants back into the general solution gives the correct solution
sol = sol /. solC // First
sol=y->Function[{x},Evaluate[sol]]  (* SOLUTION IS THIS *)


Now we verify the above solution satisfies the ode and also the initial conditions.
ode /. sol // Simplify
(* True *)

ic /. sol
(* {True,True} *)

So, what happened? Why DSolve did not solve it?

Have you tried a numerical solution?  Is there a singularity of some sort?

@mikado I just tried numerical from x=0 to x=1/2, and it works OK. For x>0.69 NDSolve becomes not happy and complains about singularity. So need to keep the range small for NDSolve to work.

I wonder if Mathematica finds the solution applicable for large x then can't solve for the initial conditions at x=0?

ode = D[y[x], {x, 2}] == D[y[x], x]*Exp[y[x]];

ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 2};


The following answer is not strictly a direct solution—although it would be nice if DSolve could handle it this way—but rather a workaround:
transformODE[ode_, change_, depvar_, ivar_] := 
 Module[{firstDeriv, secondDeriv},
  firstDeriv = 
   First @@ 
    Solve[Dt[#, ivar] /. Reverse[#] &@(change) /. Rule -> Equal, 
     D[depvar, ivar]];
  secondDeriv = 
   First @@ 
      Solve[Dt[#, {ivar, 2}] /. Reverse[#] &@(change) /. 
        Rule -> Equal, D[depvar, {ivar, 2}]] /. firstDeriv // Simplify;
  Reverse[Apart@Simplify[ode /. {firstDeriv, secondDeriv, Reverse[change]}]]];

transformIC[ic_, change_, ivar_] := {#, D[#, x]} &@(change)/.ivar -> 0 /.
Flatten[ToRules /@ ic] /. Rule -> Equal;

dSolve[{ode_, ic_}, change_, depvar_, ivar_] := 
 DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[
  ToRules@(PowerExpand@*Log /@ (First @@ (FullSimplify[
    Quiet@DSolve[{ode, ic}, depvar, ivar] /. change] /. Rule -> Equal)))];

 odeZ = transformODE[ode, z[x] -> Exp[y[x]], y[x], x];

 condsZ = transformIC[ic, z[x] -> Exp[y[x]], x];

 dSolve[{odeZ, condsZ}, z[x] -> Exp[y[x]], z[x], x]


{y -> Function[{x}, -Log[-1 + 2 E^-x]]}


This is not an answer to why but a workaround.
DSolve[{g[x] == D[y[x], x], D[g[x], x] == g[x] Exp[y[x]], y[0] == 0, 
   g[0] == 2}, {y[x], g[x]}, x] // Simplify

=>
{{y[x] -> Log[-(E^x/(-2 + E^x))], g[x] -> -(2/(-2 + E^x))}}

